# Removing * in queries when calling two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, coldfusion

I have a function that is slower than dirt in Internet Explorer but fast in firefox. I am using a select * because it is using everything in the table. I tried taking the * out and just listing all the columns but then it breaks because I am using two tables I was curious if anyone may be able to help me fix this issue. (I am using MSSQL 2012)

```
<!--- Display Table for DataTables --->
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var processTable = ''>
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
        WHERE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

**Dealer_Track_Work Table**
[image]

**Dealer_Track_Dealers**
[image]

I tried calling all columns in both rows like this:

```
<!--- Display Table for DataTables --->
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var processTable = ''>
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT id, dealerID, Date_Received, op_id, Date_Due, Date_Complete, Completed_Late, Closed_by, Rmks, Processing_Location, Item_Count, Name
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
        WHERE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you list out all of the columns?

Comment: *slower than dirt in Internet Explorer but fast in firefox* Queries execute on the database server, not on the client. So the browser has nothing to do with query speed.  If you are experiencing a difference in browser behavior, you should be looking at how the data is returned to the client.

Comment: there both processing the page around 1.43s but firefox only takes like 1/2 second to load the page and internet explorer takes like 15 seconds... i dont even know where to start =/ I removed all select * and made sure i was only calling columns that are needed... I cant just speed up internet explorer can I? lol

Comment: Start with Internet Explorer's debugging tools. Without a [repro case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or any knowledge of how much data or how it is returned to the client, there is not much we can suggest.

Comment: IE chokes on long HTML tables - Firefox is much more capable.  The data has already been fetched by CF by the time you're sending it to the client so that delay is not a server side performance problem.

Comment: Not related to your question, but your function is named displayTable and does not contain any display code.  Related to your question is that your query has no where clause.  It's probably returning more data than you need which is why it takes so long to render.

Comment: As of right now its grabbing 1000 rows within a 6 month period. I was trying to make a table that the user can see everything in the database table. Iv seen people have like 50000 rows in there table and still run faster than mine :( how do they do it! haha

Comment: lots of ways, could be the query design, could be indexes, could be better hardware, performance tuning is an art in itself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is different than stated (browser issue, not SQL) and currently there is not enough information to help diagnose the problem. An MCVE is needed.

Comment: I can just delete it if you want

Comment: Everyone could be pissed though if they lose there points :/

Comment: Ideally use the suggestions and links above to put together a [repro case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better diagnose the issue. Think about it. This is a client browser issue. Yet you have not posted any client side code. Kind of makes it hard to assist without a crystal ball, don't you think ? ;-) Right now there is not enough *relevant* information for anyone to offer more than guesses, which is not going to lead to a solution any time soon. You need to apply the suggestions offered, do some additional work on your own. Then post back with more concrete information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the SQL query is the issue?  It sounds like differences in the speed in which browsers render the results is more likely your issue.  Use SQL profiler or SSMS to execute your query directly against the database and look at the statistics.  If the query is running quickly, you need to focus your optimization efforts elsewhere.

Regarding your SQL, in order to specify column names when performing a join you need to either fully qualify the column names or alias your tables.  Also, I recommend against using implicit joins due to readability in more complex queries.

```
 SELECT dtw.id, 
    dtw.dealerID, 
    dtw.Date_Received, 
    dtw.op_id, 
    dtw.Date_Due, 
    dtw.Date_Complete, 
    dtw.Completed_Late, 
    dtw.Closed_by, 
    dtw.Rmks, 
    dtw.Processing_Location, 
    dtw.Item_Count, 
    dtd.Name
FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work dtw
JOIN dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers dtd ON dtw.dealerID = dtd.dealerID
```

Comment: .. and in terms of cfquery specifically, typically SELECT's do not need to return the same column name multiple times. If for some reason you actually did need both, you must a *column* alias, so that the two columns have different names. Otherwise, CF will only return the values from one of the columns.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to select `id` or `Rmks` is ambiguous, as both tables have such columns. If you want to query them, you should fully qualify them, like you've done in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id, -- Here!
       dealerID,
       Date_Received,
       op_id,
       Date_Due,
       Date_Complete,
       Completed_Late,
       Closed_by,
       dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.Rmks, -- And here
       Processing_Location,
       Item_Count,
       Name
FROM   dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
WHERE  dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id
```

Comment: More than one column is ambiguous - you might notice `Rmks` occurs in both

Comment: @PaulSturm nice catch, thanks. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It would also be worth suggesting a correct join here rather than the outdated syntax that is being used.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to everything else that's been said, there might be a way to get your page to render faster.  I'll describe the approach.  You can try it.

In ColdFusion, use `<cfsavecontent>` to store the display code for your query results to a variable.  Then use `toScript()` to convert that CF variable to a javascript variable.

In HTML, place an empty `<div>` container on your page.  Finally use javascript to replace the contents of the div with the javascript variable you created.